# Android Studioのライセンスに関する質問

Tags: android-studio, ライセンス

Android Studioのライセンスに関する質問があります。

Google社へ直接質問ができず、かつ別の方々ではあいまいな回答や無回答しか得られませんでしたので、確認と念のためも含めて質問をいたしました。

内容としましては、

1. Android Studioで作成されたAndroidアプリなど制作物の著作権は、Android Studioで作成した人になるのでしょうか？
2. 自由に販売や公開をしても問題ないでしょうか？
3. Android Studioは無料で使ってもいいという理解でよろしかったでしょうか？
4. Android Studioを使う上で売り上げの上限など何か規制はあるのでしょうか？

以上よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/terms?hl=ja を読んだ上でわからないのですか？また、Unityはどのプラン https://store.unity.com/ja での質問ですか？

Comment: >developer.android.com/studio/terms?hl=ja を読んだ上でわからないのですか？

すみません。
わかりずらく、かつ質問の文言を書いていないためわかりません。
ご指導、ご鞭撻のほどよろしくお願いします。